# Local geometry near a transverse intersection of two Riemann surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, intersection-theory

Suppose $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two Riemann surfaces (embedded as submanifolds in some ambient space, say, $M$) which intersect transversally at a point $p_1 \in C_1$. How does one see that near $C_1$, the surface $C_2$ appears as the fiber of $T^{*}C_1$ over $p_1$? (Edit: a reference will be quite sufficient too, and will be greatly appreciated! The context is a physics setting involving M-branes wrapping some Riemann surfaces.)

Comment: Your $M$ is probably a complex 2-dimensional manifold. And your "appears" does not make whole lot of sense. What you probably meant to say is that one can find local holomorphic coordinates on $M$ near $p_1$ such that $C_1, C_2$ correspond to open subsets of coordinate lines in ${\mathbb C}^2$, while $p_1$ corresponds to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Yes, the question was not phrased with an eye for mathematical rigor. I can rephrase it, but do you see why the second surface is roughly speaking the fiber of the cotangent bundle of the first surface? That’s the geometric picture I’m trying to understand more intuitively.